# Going From Blender Structure defined by triangles to full 3D mesh (Using GMSH?)

Tags: finite-element, mesh, gmsh, 3d

I currently have created a model airplane in Blender by drawing a closed volume with triangular planes. I want to do a FEM calculation on this object, meaning I need a fine 3D tetrahedral mesh of this structure. I have looked at threads like ([Creating 3D Mesh from stl files with gmsh](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/32679/creating-3d-mesh-from-stl-files-with-gmsh?newreg=47c2f9b8778d4adf9442470a79624e3b)) which seems similar, but having encountered issues with GMSH detecting the actual volumes from my exported .stl files, I figured I would ask this community for alternative paths before I push on any further. So:

Can anybody think of an alternative to using GMSH? Any open-source meshing programs out there worth considering?

Comment: [This forum post](http://www.elmerfem.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1927) suggest to use [e2aps](https://sourceforge.net/projects/e2aps/) for the conversion. I have not used, though.

Answer (score 3):

Tools like gmsh often require more information than STL provides -- the connectivity between triangles of the input surface mesh.
You might be interested in trying [TetWild](https://github.com/Yixin-Hu/TetWild), which can apparently reconstruct all of this connectivity information and correct for some level of degeneracy in the input data.
The paper about it is very interesting too; they tested their algorithm on several thousand surface meshes from Thingiverse.
Their algorithm was able to mesh 99% of these surface meshes, whereas many competing tools (MMG, CGAL, Tetgen) can't successfully mesh anywhere near that number.

Comment: fTetWild in particular works absolutely fantastic without much input from my side.  couldnt install TetWild for some reason.Thanks for the heads up on this package!